# How do I get the maximum of a dictionary list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Hello guys I'm new in python and I'm trying to get the item with the highest kcalorie from a dictionary list but the outout isn't correct can I know what's the problem

```
maxkcal = int()
kcaldict = { 'udon':300,'salad':150,'gyudon':500,'pasta':450}
print("The menu is:")
for key,value in kcaldict.items():
    print(key,value)
    maxkcal = max([max(kcaldict.values()) for dict in kcaldict])
print("The food with the highest calorie on the menu is :" ,key, maxkcal,"(Kcal)")
```

the output is :

```
The menu is:
udon 300
salad 150
gyudon 500
pasta 450
The food with the highest calorie on the menu is : pasta 500 (Kcal)
```

but it's supposed to be gyudon 500 not pasta

Comment: What do you mean by "dictionary list"? `kcaldict` is just a dictionary, there's no list.

Comment: `kcaldict.values())` doesn't make use of `dict`. You're just calculating the same maximum every time through the list comprehension. It also doesn't depend on `key` and `value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `max`:

```
kcaldict = { 'udon':300,'salad':150,'gyudon':500,'pasta':450}
max_key, max_val = max(kcaldict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
print("The food with the highest calorie on the menu is :" ,max_key, max_val,"(Kcal)")
```

As pointed out in the comments, I have changed the code a little bit now it will work fine.

Your code should be like this:

```
import sys
maxkcal = -sys.maxsize
maxkcal_key = None
kcaldict = { 'udon':300,'salad':150,'gyudon':500,'pasta':450}
print("The menu is:")
for key,value in kcaldict.items():
    print(key,value)
    if value > maxkcal:
        maxkcal = value
        max_key = key
print("The food with the highest calorie on the menu is :" ,max_key, maxkcal,"(Kcal)")
```

Comment: Didn't work.. are you sure?
or can you fix my code so I can know my mistake?

Comment: Let me fix your code as well but this will work I have checked it at my end.

Comment: Yeah it works thanks 
I inserted it to my code incorrectly tha'ts why it didn't work but can you fix mine anyway please?

Comment: @HazemMajeek Now check I have updated your code as well

Comment: Thanks!
Probably I should search out the sys thing because it's my first time seeing this I thought it can be solved in a simpler way. Thanks again for making my first experience on Stackoverflow good

Comment: `max(kcaldict, key=lambda x: x[1])` is just plain wrong. It just so happens to return `'gyudon'` with the OP's given input only because its second character happens to be the largest lexicographically among the keys.

Comment: @blhsing you are correct. Now I have updated the code.